# Selecting the best score per player

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, max, sql-order-by

I have a table called `Scores` which contains columns: `id`, `player_id`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3` and `date`.

The table has next following content:

```
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|  id  | player_id | value1 | value2 | value3 |    date    |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   1  |     1     |   10   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-02 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   2  |     2     |   15   |    1   |   0    | 2012-08-03 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   3  |     3     |    9   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-04 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   4  |     1     |   11   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-05 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   5  |     2     |   16   |    2   |   0    | 2012-08-06 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   6  |     2     |   15   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-07 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```

I am trying to get a query which returns the best highscore of each player ordered by the value in "value1, value2, value3". Value1 is the field with more importance, value2 medium importance and value3 minor importance, example:

```
value1 = 15                              value1 = 15
value2 = 1       is greater than ->      value2 = 0
value3 = 0                               value3 = 1
```

The expected result from the query which I need is:

```
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|  id  | player_id | value1 | value2 | value3 |    date    |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   5  |     2     |   16   |    2   |   0    | 2012-08-06 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   4  |     1     |   11   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-05 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|   3  |     3     |    9   |    0   |   0    | 2012-08-04 |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```

I'm trying with **MAX**, **DISTINCT**, **GROUP BY** and sub-queries but I don't get the correct result. Basically it is the next query but picking the first row of each "group":

```
SELECT id, player_id, value1, value2, value3
   FROM scores
   ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
```

------**EDIT 1**-------

**eggyal's answer** works fine but, maybe, the performance is not too good. I need to benchmark his solution against large database to check response times.

I have had an idea (and possible solution). The solution consists adding new **boolean column** which says if that score is the best score of that player or not. This way I need to check if the new score is better than the best old score of that player when I'm adding new score into DB, if it is I need to mark the flag as false in the old best score and as true in the new score. This gives me a way to retrieve the best score of each player directly (simple query like `SELECT ... FROM .... ORDER BY`).

------**EDIT 2**-------

**weicap's answer** is the fastest solution. I don't know why but his query is twice more faster than **eggyal's query**.

------**EDIT 3**-------
I was wrong, weicap's query is more faster if the query was cached previously, if it wasn't the query takes ten or more seconds. In change, weicap's answer always takes 300-400ms against 80.000 rows.

Comment: The problem with maintaining such a boolean column lies in the cost of determining which record holds the new "best score" on every update.  A suitable index, on the other hand, is an ordered data structure that will (at any given time) be able to fetch the maximum record for each player with very little computational effort.  Hence why I am advocating the composite index `(player_id,value1,value2,value3)` with my groupwise maximum solution -- it should prove to be extremely performant.  Grateful for any benchmark feedback you wish to provide to the contrary, however!

Comment: First **quick** benchmark against 40.000 rows with composite index and query without `LIMIT`. **eqqyal's answer** took about **600ms** and **weicap's answer** took `380ms` . I know, I need to benchmark against larger database but this first times are promising...

Comment: I'm surprised by those results... could you post the `EXPLAIN` output for my query?

Comment: @eggyal, you are right, your query is much more faster. Your solution is the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT player_id,
  (SELECT value1
   FROM Scores b where a.player_id=b.player_id  ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC limit 1) as value1,
  (SELECT value2
   FROM Scores b where a.player_id=b.player_id  ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC limit 1) as value2,
  (SELECT value3
   FROM Scores b where a.player_id=b.player_id  ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC limit 1) as value3

FROM Scores a GROUP BY player_id order by value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
```

or something like

```
SELECT * FROM Scores a 

where id =(SELECT id
   FROM Scores b where a.player_id=b.player_id  ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC limit 1)

GROUP BY player_id order by value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
```

Comment: First query is **twice** more faster than second. I think first query is the best solution.

Comment: As I said on my main post, weicap's solution is the fastest query.

Answer (score 5):

For each `value`, you can obtain the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT * FROM Scores NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, value1, value2, MAX(value3) value3 FROM Scores NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, value1, MAX(value2) value2         FROM Scores NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, MAX(value1) value1                 FROM Scores
    GROUP BY player_id) t
    GROUP BY player_id) t
    GROUP BY player_id) t
ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97ad7/1/0).

Comment: It seems to be really slow, isn't it? Yes, this will work. But I wouldn't want this on large datasets.

Comment: @Nemoden: Using the composite index `(player_id,value1,value2,value3)` it ought to be pretty performant.  It's worth benchmarking against any other solution.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be better performance-wise now and seem to work as OP expected +1. Your first solution actually works, it's just my "thing" - to care about performance :)

Comment: This solution works perfectly! but I'm worried about performance, I need to test against a table with thousands of rows.

Comment: @Morpheo17: As mentioned [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106613/mysql-selecting-the-best-score-per-player#comment16182947_12106937), you should find that the composite index `(player_id,value1,value2,value3)` gives good performance.  I'd be interested to hear your results.

Comment: @eggyal I have another idea to resolve this query, can you read my _edit_ on the main question and tell us what do you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an index on `(player_id, value1, value2, value3)` and then this query:

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM 
        Scores AS s
    JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              player_id
          FROM 
              Scores
        ) AS p
      ON s.id =
         ( SELECT
               id
           FROM 
               Scores AS b
           WHERE
               b.player_id = p.player_id
           ORDER BY
               value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
           LIMIT 1
         ) 
ORDER BY
    s.value1 DESC, s.value2 DESC, s.value3 DESC ;
```

Comment: As always ypercube, you outclass me!  +1  :)

Comment: @eggyal: I have to say that I like the triple grouping in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual scores are: 1000, 1510, 900, etc... You got the idea? 
It's like decimal numbers where position of a single digit matter. 
You can convert your 3 values to a single one to group by it and you can estimate it either on-the-fly (right in query) or you can pre-calculate it (before you write it to the table).

Comment: Need to know in advance the maximum length/size of each value.

Comment: Well, yes, - you have to. Supposedly, OP knows it.

Comment: Not necessarily... but one could design a query to obtain and use that information from the data in the table.

Comment: eggyal is right, I don't know in advance the maximum lenght of each value.

Comment: That's can be a problem then. No way you can value scores from 0 to 100? It would be a slight redesign, but... by chance, can it be a better one?

Comment: @Morpheo17, If you don't mind I will keep this answer for a while

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using (other than SQL)? It would be easiest if the SQL could sort it, but I don't think that this is possible. If you are using PHP, then you could just place it in a for loop, add an index to the array such as 'bestScore' and then check each score individually like so:

```
//Extract Data Here
for($outI=0;$outI<count($scores);$outI++){
    $scores[$outI]['bestScore'] = 0;
    for($innI=0;$innI<=3;$innI++){
        if ($scores[$outI]['value' . $innI+1] > $scores[$outI]['bestScore'])
            $scores[$outI]['bestScore'] = $scores[$outI]['value' . $innI+1];
    }
    echo 'The best score for ' . $scores[$outI]['player_id'] . ' was ' . $scores[$outI]['bestScore'] . '.<br />';
}
```

If it works as expected, it should list the best scores for each player.

Comment: guess what happens if he's got millions of players

Comment: I prefer not to use another language because the table can contains thousands of rows and the memory to retrieve all rows to get the best score per player is inadmissible.

Comment: That's a good point. But the SQL still has to run through it all. Is mysql faster than PHP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your maximum sore can be 16 try this,

```
Select Scores.* from Scores, (SELECT player_id,max(17*17*value1+17*value2+value3) 
as max_score  FROM Scores group by player_id)t where 
(17*17*value1+17*value2+value3) = t.max_score and Scores.player_id=t.player_id
```

Comment: And if the maximum score is not known, as [already stated by the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106613/mysql-selecting-the-best-score-per-player#comment16182458_12106699)?

Comment: @eggyal then this won't work, anyways I just saw your solution, and that is much better.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, player_id, value1, value2, value3, `date`
   FROM scores
   ORDER BY value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
) x 
GROUP BY player_id
order by value1 DESC, value2 DESC, value3 DESC
```

Comment: -1 As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):  "*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*".  Therefore one cannot rely on the `ORDER BY` clause employed in your subquery to ensure that the maximum record is selected from each group, as desired.