# MySQL - Reporting on minimum and maximum Track and Field results from multiple rows of one table and joining data from multiple other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with athletic data, wherein I need to output a report with the following column headers:

Player GUID, Player Full Name, 100 Meter Best, 100 Meter Best Date, 200 Meter Best, 200 Meter Best Date, Shotput Best, Shotput Best Date, Discus Best, Discus Best Date, Long Jump Best, Long Jump Best Date

It is important to note that "Best Results" for the running events will be their smallest value for that sport and for the Field events, the best result will be their greatest value.

The data is organized in a less than ideal manner, but here are examples of minimized versions of the tables that I'll need for the report:

**players**

| id | guid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2c637b23-0de5-5af2-b2a8-3556c2230a1a | Bob Loblaw |

**player_years**

This odd table is used to track the data about the player's year, such as the school they attended, but for our purpose it is used by the player_year_metrics table and will be used to give us the player_id. Each player may have multiple player_year rows.

| id | player_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

**player_year_metric_types**

In the real database, there are many metric types. In this example, these are the ones I need.

| id | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 Meter |
| 2 | 200 Meter |
| 3 | Shotput |
| 4 | Discus |
| 5 | Long Jump |

**player_year_metrics**

In this table, each row corresponds to a separate metric. Each athlete has many rows.

| id | results | metric_type_id | player_year_id | event_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10.5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | 12 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 20 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

**events**

The events table will supply us with the date of the metric's result.

| id | occurred_on |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2023 |
| 2 | 2/2/2023 |
| 3 | 3/3/2023 |

I'm new to SQL, but I've tried using the logic in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106613/selecting-the-best-score-per-player) to see if I could simply populate the 100 Meter Best value, but received an error code "Subquery returns more than one row". I'm not really sure where to go from here.

```
SELECT players.guid, players.name, (SELECT MIN(value) AS '100 Meter Best' from player_year_metrics where metric_type_id = 26 GROUP BY player_year_id)
FROM players
JOIN player_years ON players.id=player_years.player_id
JOIN player_year_metrics ON player_years.id=player_year_metrics.player_year_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just move the subquery from your SELECT and turn it into a LEFT JOIN instead. Try this:

```
SELECT players.guid, players.name, pym.100mb AS '100 Meter Best'
FROM players
JOIN player_years ON players.id=player_years.player_id
JOIN player_year_metrics ON player_years.id=player_year_metrics.player_year_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(value) AS '100mb', player_year_id 
       FROM player_year_metrics 
     WHERE metric_type_id = 26 
     GROUP BY player_year_id) pym
 ON  player_years.id=pym.player_year_id;
```

Comment: I ran this today, and unfortunately it results in many duplicates of one individual with null 100 Meter Best values.

Comment: The reason for duplicates is not from the subquery of the `LEFT JOIN` because that subquery itself will only return a single `MIN(value)` for distinctive `player_year_id`. Therefore, the duplicates are coming from your other joins. Let me see what I can do with your sample data.

Comment: Take a look at this tests @Jared   >  https://dbfiddle.uk/PRLxTL4F